# How can we adapt the knitr to out own directories?

Tags: r, knitr

The following codes do not run:

````
```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
knitr::opts_knit$set(root.dir = rprojroot::find_rstudio_root_file())
```
````

Because the second line generates the following error:

```
Error: No root directory found in C:/Users/asus/Desktop/RTEST or its parent directories. 
Root criterion: contains a file matching "[.]Rproj$" with contents matching "^Version: " in the first line
```

How can I fix this code?

Comment: Are you actually working in a RStudio project? That's not the default. Where exactly is your `Rproj` file located in relation to your markdown document? Where exactly do you want the files to go?

Comment: Honestly, now I do not need to do that. But if you can explain what knitr, and those codes work I would be so happy, I could not find on google enough explanation. Many thanks Mr. Flick.